# Regex to match a dash that is not followed by an "@" character

Tags: php, regex

Hi I am trying to use a regex to replace a "/" with "/n:". The problem I am having is that I want this to happen unless the "/" is followed by an "@" so "/@".

I had a pattern like this "//[^@]/" and while this gets the "/" while ignoring any "/@" it also matches the following letter. I just need to match the "/". Can anyone help with this thanks.

Edit: Added example string

```
/module/y-version/@value
```

Comment: add your example string....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
'~/(?!@)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW8uF1/1)

The `[^@]` is a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), and is a *consuming* pattern, while the lookahead will only check the text to the right of the current location in the string, and will fail the match if the lookahead pattern finds the match.